# Convert UTC time to specific time zone in Azure ADX Kusto query

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have millions of records in Azure Data Explorer. Each of this record has a timestamp value associated with it. I want to be able to convert this timestamp value in the specific time zone.

For example in SQL I use AT TIME ZONE to convert timestamp value from one zone into another -

```
Select CONVERT(datetime, timestampvalueColumn) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time' as 'TimeInEST' from Table;
```

I am not willing to use offset value as it doesn't support daylight saving changes.

How I can do this with Kusto query language in ADX?

Comment: Is what you need is indeed US Eastern Standard Time?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz nope. Not always EST. It could be other timezones as well

Comment: There is no native support in KQL. Do you have the python plugin enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pythonplugin?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: How do you know what is the relevant TZ?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz The values stored in ADX are in UTC timezone. We have multiple timezones in which we want them to be converted. I took EST as an example.

Comment: Storing datetime in UTC is the only option, therefore the question: How do you know what is the relevant TZ? Do you have an additional field indicating the TZ/country/etc. or you have a list (maybe in your head :-)) that maps a cluster/database to a TZ?

Comment: Nope there is no such field we have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Kusto team is moving fast :-)

Support for [timezones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/timezone) conversion has been added:

- datetime_local_to_utc()
- datetime_utc_to_local()

---

```
// Sample generation. Not part of the solution
let t = materialize(range i from 1 to 15 step 1 | extend dt_utc = ago(rand()*365d*10));
// Solution Starts here
t
| extend dt_et = datetime_utc_to_local(dt_utc, "US/Eastern")
| extend offset = dt_et - dt_utc
```

| i | dt_utc | dt_et | offset |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2012-12-03T17:24:51.6057076Z | 2012-12-03T12:24:51.6057076Z | -05:00:00 |
| 14 | 2012-12-10T05:04:17.8507406Z | 2012-12-10T00:04:17.8507406Z | -05:00:00 |
| 10 | 2013-03-23T14:42:00.4276416Z | 2013-03-23T10:42:00.4276416Z | -04:00:00 |
| 15 | 2013-10-01T06:28:36.4665806Z | 2013-10-01T02:28:36.4665806Z | -04:00:00 |
| 11 | 2017-07-18T06:10:30.9963876Z | 2017-07-18T02:10:30.9963876Z | -04:00:00 |
| 3 | 2017-11-17T21:57:58.4443366Z | 2017-11-17T16:57:58.4443366Z | -05:00:00 |
| 6 | 2018-05-09T03:36:24.7533896Z | 2018-05-08T23:36:24.7533896Z | -04:00:00 |
| 12 | 2018-06-05T17:36:41.7970716Z | 2018-06-05T13:36:41.7970716Z | -04:00:00 |
| 4 | 2018-08-03T16:25:19.9323686Z | 2018-08-03T12:25:19.9323686Z | -04:00:00 |
| 8 | 2019-02-21T17:33:52.9957996Z | 2019-02-21T12:33:52.9957996Z | -05:00:00 |
| 2 | 2020-09-24T18:37:08.0049776Z | 2020-09-24T14:37:08.0049776Z | -04:00:00 |
| 1 | 2020-12-09T19:57:23.7480626Z | 2020-12-09T14:57:23.7480626Z | -05:00:00 |
| 7 | 2021-01-17T13:42:55.0632136Z | 2021-01-17T08:42:55.0632136Z | -05:00:00 |
| 9 | 2021-03-04T23:44:01.7192366Z | 2021-03-04T18:44:01.7192366Z | -05:00:00 |
| 13 | 2022-06-04T16:26:57.8826486Z | 2022-06-04T12:26:57.8826486Z | -04:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OQQuCQBBG74L/4cOTRmUSdYmOXbtIZxna0RbWHVlHiOjHt2aHjsPw3vvKEjX1g2N07DmQWvFbXEUxUFBIC30wRnHT/EkTxwrFGT0pB0vOvjgP5DuGRRukRwUVVAeMykM83uCnsjcw2kx6jyR1MhMmL1b748Gsql1RnNKkjEN%20FdQa2yMeHDhNNE3%20JTzXTayr7XlWNiqNkzu5fEmskd3q8kJxQPBZ8UdL244L/tVsfps%20jczLzwMBAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a convenience function using a similar ideia of the function given bellow. Note that the conversion works for DST (Daylight Saving Time) as well. You just need a way to map a place to its timezone string. In the function that follows, the mapping is from a Brazilian state abbreviation to its timezone string.
See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/timezone) for a list of available timezones.

```
.create-or-alter function with (
    docstring = 'Dada uma UF e um datetime (UTC), retorna o horário local. Não é tratado o GMT-5 ao oeste de AM.'
) ToLocalDatetime(state: string, dtutc: datetime) {
    let selected_tz = iff('GO,DF,MG,ES,RJ,SP,PR,SC,RS' has state, 'America/Sao_Paulo',
        iff('MA,PI,CE,RN,PB' has state, 'America/Fortaleza',
        iff('AL,SE' has state, 'America/Maceio',
        iff('BA' == state, 'America/Bahia',
        iff('RR' == state, 'America/Boa_Vista',
        iff('MS' == state, 'America/Campo_Grande',
        iff('MT' == state, 'America/Cuiaba',
        iff('AM' == state, 'America/Manaus',
        iff('PA,AP' has state, 'America/Belem',
        iff('AC' == state, 'America/Rio_Branco',
        iff('RO' == state, 'America/Porto_Velho',
        iff('PE' == state, 'America/Recife',
        iff('TO' == state, 'America/Araguaina', '')))))))))))));
    let localdt = datetime_utc_to_local(dtutc, selected_tz);
    let dt_hr = split(format_datetime(localdt, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), " ");
    iff(isnotempty(localdt), 
        strcat(dt_hr[0], "T", dt_hr[1], format_timespan(localdt - dtutc, "HH:mm")),
        '')
}
```

A couple tests at the moment when DST ended in the `DF` Brazilian state:

`print(ToLocalDatetime('DF', datetime('2019-02-17 01:00:00')))`

Output: `2019-02-16T23:00:00-02:00`

`print(ToLocalDatetime('DF', datetime('2019-02-17 02:00:00')))`

Outputs `2019-02-16T23:00:00-03:00`

I agree with other answers stating that is better to do it on the client side for most cases. Additionally, the `iff` sequence of the function is ugly. For a more elegant solution, it is possible to define a datatable such as:

```
datatable(state:string, tz:string) [
        'GO,DF,MG,ES,RJ,SP,PR,SC,RS', 'America/Sao_Paulo',
        'MA,PI,CE,RN,PB', 'America/Fortaleza',
......
```

However, if you to it you cannot use the function on some scenarios, due to [documented restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#restrictions-on-the-use-of-user-defined-functions).

Answer (score -1):

Usually the answer is "Don't do it in Kusto", do it in the client that is reading the results from Kusto, which most certainly will have a "utc-to-local-time" or "utc-to-this-timezone" functions.

Comment: I agree. It is better to do it in client side.